# Discord.py Interaction Failed

Tags: python, discord, bots, interaction

So I'm making a Discord bot and I'm relatively new to its API. I want buttons to be able to edit the embeds without sending a message or any sort of response to the user. However, if I try to send an empty response or no response at all it says "this interaction failed" every time the button is clicked. If I add something like content = 'text' to respond it works, but I don't want to send anything. Here is my code:

```py
 @commands.command()
  async def assist(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Commands', description = 'sdgsdgsdgds', color = 0x0099ff)
    message =  await ctx.send(
      embed = embed,
      components = self.buttons
      )
    while True:
      event = await self.client.wait_for('button_click')
      if event.channel is not ctx.channel:
        return
      if event.channel == ctx.channel:
        response = event.component.id
        if response is None:
          await event.channel.send('Something went wrong. Please try again.')
        if event.channel == ctx.channel:
          if response == '1':
            await message.edit(embed = discord.Embed(title = 'New', description = 'HDFGSFGS'))
            await event.respond()
```

Comment: I don't believe "button_click" is a valid discord.py event, you should define a button callback instead: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=logging#discord.ui.Button.callback

Comment: It is, the code all works I just need a solution for the problem I laid out. the very last line that is, it only works if I do await event.respond(content = 'message'). I do not however want to have to send the user a message every time they click the button just to produce a valid interaction.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on the official docs

```
while True:
      event = await self.client.wait_for('button_click')
      if event.channel is not ctx.channel:
        return
      if event.channel == ctx.channel:
        response = event.component.id
        if response is None:
          await event.channel.send('Something went wrong. Please try again.')
        if event.channel == ctx.channel:
          if response == '1':
            await event.edit_origin(
               embed = discord.Embed(title = 'New', description = 'HDFGSFGS')
            )
```